# What to do with "Internet Explorer has closed this webpage to help protect your computer"?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I switched from IE 6 to IE8. Now when I open some pages I used to open for many years already they sometimes do open and sometimes I see a message "Internet Explorer has closed this webpage to help protect your computer" and so I have to just open the same page in Firefox.

Since I like having two browsers with different settings (one showing pictures and one not showing pictures) I'd really to be able to open any page in any of the browsers.

How do I treat that new IE8 behavior and make it just open the page and not bother me with useless messages?

Answer (score 1):

Hum ... change browser :-)
You have to change the settings of security in IE Preferences panel.

Comment: What exactly do I change so that I don't make my computer vulnerable?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried compatibility view for the website and see if the problem still exists.